# How to write documentation of my functions in angular

Tags: angular, documentation

I want to write documentation of my Angular project. Can anyone guide me what is the default way to write documentation for Angular? I have searched it online but unable to find any answer. All I found is something related to `compodoc`. But I want to document each and every function of my project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If you're building an AngularJS (1.x) project:** 
Many javascript developers use JSDoc as a way to document their code (http://usejsdoc.org/).

**If you are building an Angular(2+) project:** 
Microsoft released a standard for typescript projects: https://github.com/Microsoft/tsdoc